# Fitness function for portfolio optimisation using GA

Tags: r

I am currently trying to generate optimal weights using GA for portfolio optimisation as I know the sum of all the weights for a portfolio should equal one however my current project returns a sum greater than 1 on every run and I am wondering how I can fix this

```
    install.packages("quantmod")
    library(quantmod)

install.packages("GA") 
library(GA)

myStocks <- c("DIS", "MSFT", "O", "JNJ", "RTX", "V", "T", "JPM", "BMY", "TSN")

Stocks = lapply(myStocks, function(myStocks) {
  dailyReturn(na.omit(getSymbols(myStocks, src="yahoo", from="2019-01-01", to="2020-01-01", auto.assign=FALSE)))
})

meanReturn <- colMeans(do.call(merge, Stocks))

covariance <- cov(do.call(merge, Stocks))



f = function(x) {
  
  port_returns <- (sum(x * meanReturn))
  port_risk <- sum(x * (covariance * x))

}



GA <- ga(type = "real-valued", fitness = f, lower = rep(0,10), upper = rep(1,10))
summary(GA)
sum(GA@solution)
```